# Surface plotting with ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, mapping, surface

Is it possible to plot with ggplot2 3D surface which is presented as (x, y, z)-vector with labeled countour lines?

Desired result is presented below
[Surface map with countour lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdXCD.png)

Comment: You might have a look at this library: https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/reference/geom_text_contour.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the geomtextpath package was built for.

Example copied from `?geomtextpath::geom_textcontour`

```r
library(geomtextpath)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(nrow(volcano)), y = seq(ncol(volcano)))
df$z <- as.vector(volcano)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_filled(bins = 6, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_textcontour(bins = 6, size = 2.5, padding = unit(0.05, "in")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = terrain.colors(11)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: For the record, @allancameron I still think that the package should have been called `ggtextpath` ;)